# What mechanisms exist for generating lift on a static object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, air, aircraft

What mechanisms exist for generating lift on a static object?

Condition is: **Other than propellers**

I know that generating lift on a static object in a sense of anti-gravity for e.g. drone is not possible, to my knowledge, however which current up to date physics application can "cheat/emulate" generating lift on a static object.

Could something else except classic propellers be used to make an object (e.g. size of a 2-3 feet long vehicle/drone model) flying?

I would like to know answer to my question from "physics"point of view, before going to engineering room and finding more facts there.

So, are there other possibilities except classic propellers?

You can touch my question from 2 points of view:

1) Amateur - meaning I don't have access to the latest technologies they are using for experimental flying machines in the army

2) Godlike - meaning I have access to the latest technologies they are using for experimental flying machines in the army

Comment: It seems to me you're really asking what mechanisms exist for generating lift on a static object. I would edit your title to remove contentious words like "anti-gravity".

Comment: OK, thanks. I can correct it. What title would you suggest. I am not native English speaker, so I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Hi Derfder, I'm closing this post as _Not a real question_ until you (or someone else?) edits it into a coherent on-topic question that avoids the word [anti-gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-gravity), which is off-topic.

Comment: @Qmechanic yep, the term "anti-gravity" comes rather from science fiction than from physics... However, note that it can be adressed in a fun way in the context of supergravity as explained [here](http://uduality.blogspot.de/2012/11/antigravity-from-supergravity.html) ... ;-)

Comment: Reopen vote since the offending content has apparently been removed.

Comment: @Derfder: how about "what mechanisms exist for generating lift on a static object" and then add the restriction other than propellers (so no helicopters) in the body of the question.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks I have edited as you suggested.

Comment: I've voted to reopen :-)

Comment: Well, rockets (incl. mass drivers) and magnetic levitation are the methods I know about off the top of my head, though I don't know what you consider "static" and whether you would consider these "Godlike" powers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is not a physics answer, but perhaps it could point the way to one. Although: [Here's some physics](http://kmoddl.org/papers/Alife06_Regan.pdf).*

**Assuming that with "static" you mean "hovering", I think an [ornithopter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithopter) (from Greek *ornithos* "bird" and *pteron* "wing") could do the trick.**

It looks like fun! And...

The [hobby variety](http://www.ornithopter.org) seems to be able hover.

> [image]
>   **2008.** I built this four-winged RC ornithopter for a demonstration at IIT Bombay. It represents a concept for a manned ornithopter at 1/10th scale. The wingspan is 36 inches. The four-winged design gives this ornithopter excellent slow-flight capabilities, and it can even be configured for hovering flight.

[*Source*](http://www.ornithopter.org/history.electric.shtml)

And so can a possibly military version. Not the mean machine you'd expect! :)

> [image] Because ornithopters can be made to resemble birds or insects, they could be used for military applications, such as aerial reconnaissance without alerting the enemies that they are under surveillance. Several ornithopters have been flown with video cameras on board, some of which can hover and maneuver in small spaces. [In 2011, AeroVironment, Inc. announced a remotely piloted ornithopter resembling a large hummingbird for possible spy missions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AeroVironment_Nano_Hummingbird)

[*Source*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithopter#Applications_for_unmanned_ornithopters)

Comment: + It could be argued that this a propeller, but anyway I like it!

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Birds have propellers? Good luck arguing that with an ornithologist. :)

Comment: If by propeller the OP means any sort of airfoil to which power is applied, it remains attached to the vehicle, and its lift vector can be directed upwards.

Answer (score 1):

Hot air balloons shaped like bees.

[image]

[*Source: Ruth Ellison from Canberra, Australia*](http://www.ruthellison.com/)